# Need .htaccess File to Force URL to be /abc than being ?a=abc

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've a script(.php & smarty combined) which displays pages like ?a=abc, whereas I would like it to display the requested pages as /abc. Below I've the code that does exactly the same as I want, but the problem is whenever I access /?a=abc, it displays the pages but doesn't converts the URL as /abc in the address bar. So can you guys please help on this?

Here's the code I'm using in the .htaccess file of my website:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?a=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?a=$1 [L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Chane your Rewrite condition to :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (?:/|/index\.php)\?a=([^\s&]+) [NC]
```

Now it will match  **/?a=foo** or **/index.php?a=foo**